# Как написать алгоритм решения примера в виде строки на kotlin

Tags: kotlin, eval

Раньше я через scriptenginemanager использовал eval(), для решения примеров, представленных в виде строки, но возникли проблемы с десятичными числами, так как я могу написать подобный алгоритм или где я могу найти нужную мне информацию?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, что-то из этого вам поможет: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html Или: https://play.kotlinlang.org/

Answer (score 0):

А так разве нельзя?

```
with(ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")) {
    val result = eval("2 + 2")
    println("Result=$result)
}
```

Comment: Можно, я даже так и сделал, но при счёте напрмер 2.5-2.3 будет 0.199999999..., именно поэтому я хочу написать алгоритм сам, чтобы приводить числа к bigdecimal

Comment: Ну это непростое упражнение... Надо писать пАрсер, дерево инструкций, либо польскую инверсную запись, либо что-то мутить с аналогом стека и т.д.

Comment: У меня есть тренировочный прожект, если хотите дайте ссылку на свой github аккаунт - приглашу, посмотрите код